# PHP Infinite While Loop, Unknown Cause

Tags: php, while-loop, infinite

```
<?php
$i=1;
while ($i<=$totalpages) {
    if (($i>=($page-5) && $i<=($page+5) && $i<$totalpages) || $i==1 || ($i+1>$totalpages)) {

        echo "<td><a href=\"search.php?page=$i\">";
        if ($i=$page) {
        echo "<strong>  $i  </strong>";
        }
        if ($i!=$page) {
        echo "  $i  ";
        }
        echo "</a></td>";
        }
    $i++;
    }

?>
```

Trying to build a webpage that ouputs some search values neat the bottom of the page, however I keep getting an infinite loop. I've no Idea about what's causing it, and would like someone elses insight into the problem at hand.

Comment: Replace `$i = 1` with `$i == 1` in `while`-loop.

Comment: Your if-statement is quite complicated. I would recommend replacing it with something like: `if(CheckSomeCondition($i, $page, $totalPages)){ ... }`, then do the actual logic of the `if`-check in a more readable fashion in that method (that would probably make it easier for you to find the problem yourself, too).

Answer (score 2):

Your if condition has a problem

Change

```
$i =1
```

with

```
$i==1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of places that you reset $i, inadvertently I assume

`$i=1`

and

`$i=$page`

replace them with `==`

Comment: Well, it resets the variable and returns true as the value has been set succesfully

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        $i=1;
        while ($i<=$totalpages) {
            if (($i>=($page-5) && $i<=($page+5) && $i<$totalpages) || $i == 1|| ($i+1>$totalpages)) {

                echo "<td><a href=\"search.php?page=$i\">";
                if ($i == $page) {
                echo "<strong>  $i  </strong>";
                }
                if ($i!=$page) {
                echo "  $i  ";
                }
                echo "</a></td>";
                }
            $i++;
            }
?>
```

**Changes in 1st and second if condition.**
1) $i == 1
2) $i == $page

Comment: Yup, that's fixed it, thanks for pointit out my own stupidity. :)

Comment: Most welcome, always take a time while deciding a conditions it will save your time and make your software bug free.

Answer (score 0):

is there a reason why this can not be accomplished using a for loop ? While loops are always risky and easy to cause problems if there is a scenario to cause to loop for ever.

eg.

```
for ($i = 0; $i<=$totalpages; $i++){
 // do something
}
```

Comment: He has multiple conditions

Comment: TRUE but he could still do this with a for loop, all that's happening is he is looping through a list of page numbers and making the active page number bold

Answer (score 0):

There is some issues in the conditions

first: the

> || $i=1||

allways return true. 
Change for

> || $i==1||

Second: The same case of adobe

> if ($i=$page) //Allways return try is assignation operation

Change to:

> if ($i==$page)